# How to fix ‘Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerables<>’ An explicate conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m creating a web API in MVC.  The database is (thus far) simple, only three tables.  I am unable to join them, though.  I’ve tried three different methods for joining tables in the controller, and all return the same error, which is:

> Cannot covert type (something*) to
>   ‘Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerables< SalesDbApi.Sample>’ An
>   explicate conversion exists.  Are you missing a cast?

(* The "something" portion is different depending on how the join occurs but the rest of the message remains the same, so I am assuming it is the relevant part.)

I’m guessing there is something wrong with how I have setup my Entity Relationships in Linq, because if I don’t do a join and just do a select all from Sample I get the following JSON back:

```
{"SampleId":10,"Barcode":"863760","CreatedAt":"2016-01-25T00:00:00","CreatedBy":10,"StatusID":3,"User":null,"Status":null}
```

User and Status aren’t fields in the Sample table.  They are the names of the tables I am trying to link with, so I wouldn't expect them to appear.

Any idea on what I've done wrong?

Here are my three models:

Users.cs

```
namespace SalesDbApi
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User()
        {
            this.Samples = new HashSet<Sample>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Statuses.cs

```
namespace SalesDbApi
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Status
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Status()
        {
            this.Samples = new HashSet<Sample>();
        }

        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        public string Status1 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Samples.cs

```
namespace SalesDbApi
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Sample
    {
        public int SampleId { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public int StatusID { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here’s the code from the controller

SalesUsersController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using SalesDbApi;

namespace SalesProject.Controllers
{
    public class SalesUsersController : ApiController
    {
        webapitestdbEntities1 db = new webapitestdbEntities1();

        public IEnumerable<Sample> Get()
        {

            {
               db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                var query = from x in db.Samples
                            join q in db.Users
                            on x.CreatedBy equals q.UserId
                            select q.FirstName;
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your query is selecting only the `FirstName` property of `User` not `Sample` - Best guess is you want `select x` (not `select q.FirstName`) although its unclear why you need a `join` here if your only want to return a collection of `Sample` If you want to return other properties of `User`, then you need to project the results into a view model containing those properties.

Comment: I tried selecting several fields but all got the same error seemingly since it's being pulled from the joined table.  When I tried selecting x I got the results mentioned above ({"SampleId":10,"Barcode":"123","CreatedAt":"2016-01-25T00:00:00","CreatedBy":10,"StatusID":3,"User":null,"Status":null})  All of those fields come from the sample table except for user and status, which are not fields in any table; they are references to other tables set as public virtual classes in the sample.cs model

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

Comment: Read my first comment again.If you want fields from multiple tables, you cannot return a collection of `Sample` - you need to return a collection of a model that contains the properties you want - `select new MyModel { SampleId = x.SampleId, FirstName = q.FirstName, ..... }`

Comment: How would I setup that model?

Comment: It would just contain each of the properties of `Sample`, `User` and `Status` that you want to display in the view (I don't know which of them you want)

Comment: I added the following model (groupquery.cs), but my controller cannot access it:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SalesDbApi;

namespace SalesProject.Models
{
    public class groupquery
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Sample> SamplesFromProj { get; set; }
        public virtual User UserFromProj { get; set; }
        public virtual Status StatusFromProj { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Read my last comment - your model needs to contain a property for each item of `Sample`, `User` and `Status` that you want to include in the view! (not properties for those objects). Do you want to display the `Barcode` value from `Sample`? - if so include `public string Barcode { get; set; }`. Do you want to include the `FirstName` value from `User`? - if so include `public string FirstName { get; set; }` etc.

Comment: I'm not understanding.  This isn't using view, it's returning JSON for API.  I just don't see specifically what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It makes no difference!

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying.  It's not giving me the error now.  I'm going to play around with this some more to make sure i really have it, but meanwhile, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think table Samples or table users not a data in database. besause linq can't accommodate table with no data.

Comment: They are both there. If I try to return data from any single table through the controller, it returns.  The error only occurs when I try to join tables.

Comment: maybe the joins table is not data relation, finaly the join is not data found. Try join manually in SQL query, there any data or not?

Comment: Yeah, even manual joins gave me the same error.  I've had it work for me before when I was doing web apps in MVC.  This is the first time I've created a web api this way, so I am wondering if there is some difference between the two that causes it to work in one but not the other.